# HttpContext in Razor Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I tried to port some ASPX markup to Razor, but compiler threw an error.

ASPX (works fine):

```
<% if (node.IsAccessibleToUser(Context)) { %>
    // markup
<% } %>
```

CSHTML (throws an error):

```
@if (node.IsAccessibleToUser(Context)) {
    // markup
}
```

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Web.HttpContextBase' to 'System.Web.HttpContext'

How to get reference to `HttpContext` in Razor view? Is it correct to use `HttpContext.Current` or I need to check site map node visibility in a different way?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

WebViewPage.Context is HttpContextBase instance. WebViewPage.Context.ApplicationInstance.Context is HttpContext instance.

```
@if (node.IsAccessibleToUser(Context.ApplicationInstance.Context)) {
    // markup
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use `HttpContext.Current`. This will give you access to the request and response data.

Comment: You can use it, but I would suggest using it in your Controllers, or creating an HTML helper.

Comment: @Martin, could you please clarify about Controller/HtmlHelper ?

Answer (score 2):

What @Martin means is that you could write some extension methods on your Node class (whatever the type of that is), like:

```
public static class NodeExtensions
{
    public static bool IsAccessibleToUser(this Node node)
    {
        // access HttpContext through HttpContext.Current here 
    }
}
```

and use it in your view like:

```
@if(node.IsAccessibleToUser()) {}
```

Thus removing the dependency on HttpContext in your view.